# jQuery Tablesorter - in IE it reverses the sort order every time I trigger the sort operation

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I make an AJAX call and update numerical values in a column of my table (I don't append new rows or delete existing rows, just update the values inside the column I wish to sort on).

After the AJAX call is successful, I just run:
`$("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[4,0]]} );` to sort on column 4 in ASC order.

However in IE, every time the above code runs, it reverses the current order. So **the table flips from being ordered ASC to DESC to ASC to DESC...**

I tried instead calling `$("#myTable").trigger("update");` but this still switches the sort order in IE.

Any idea how to sort this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tablesorter, after inserting/modifying the table you have to `.trigger("update")` and `.trigger("sorton", ...)` to reimplement the current sort.

However, due to the way "update" is implemented, you can't simply have two consecutive statements, `.trigger("update")` followed by `.trigger("sorton", ...)`. This is counter-intuitive and generally regarded as a bug.

The whole thing is perfectly explained [here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/code/376219). Apply the suggested patch to your copy of tablesorter, and use the following single statement to achieve the combined affect of updating tablesorter's internal representation of the table and re-applying the current sort:

```
$("#myTable").trigger({type:'update', resort:true});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. To be honest I'm not sure if that sorted it or not. The problem with my table was I had some cells with blank data, all the others were numeric. After I explicitly set blank columns to be 0, IE started working fine.

Comment: It's possible you needed both the patch and the zeros.

Comment: It's working without the patch ;) Just calling the .tablesorter method after each AJAX call and it's all good! Cheers though for mentioning the fix. At least I know where to look if something like this happens in the future!

Comment: Yes, calling `$("#myTable").tablesorter()` after updating the table's contenets will work but it's a brute force approach. As long as the `table`, `thead` and `tbody` tags have not been replaced then `$("#myTable").trigger({type:'update', resort:true});` (with the patch in place) is friendlier and will allow the last sort to be reapplied.